# Getting data through joins in django models

Tags: python, django

I want to join the models based on a key to get the query results. Models are:

```
class UserDiscountProfiles (models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey("users.User")
    profile = models.ForeignKey(DiscountProfiles)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class DiscountProfiles(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    profileType = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
```

My function will pass me DiscountProfiles.pk and i want to use it to filter the users in UserDiscountProfiles model and once i have the user id of all users associated with the certain profile i would like to get the user's attributes like user first name/last name etc.

Any ideas how to do this through django queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correct, you want to get user detail from `users` model through `UserDiscountProfiles`, All you have to do is use `ForeignKey` relation that you already have in your `UserDiscountProfiles` model to `users.User` model.

```
udetail = UserDiscountProfiles.objects.filter(profile=1)

for u in udetail:
    u.user.first_name
```

This will return first_name from `users.User` model

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Aaqib, this seems to be a more systematic way of doing it using power of django models.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
udp= UserDiscountProfiles.objects.filter(profile__pk= 1).values('user__id', 'user__first_name','user__last_name') # for example we think pk is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the many to many field in `DiscountProfile`

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="UserDiscountProfiles", verbose_name="list of users", related_name="discountprofiles")
```

Then you can traverse both ways as...

```
dp = DiscountProfile.objects.get(...)

for u in dp.users:
    ...
```

Or

```
u = User.objects.get(...)

for dp in u.discountprofiles:
    ...
```